# I have a scheduled task, but if the server that is executing the scheduled task fails, how do I find it and let it execute the scheduled task again

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

My mother tongue is not English, so maybe some places look strange, I will try my best to explain.

I'm using a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` to schedule the tasks,that's pretty straightforward.

But once my machine or service is restarted, the tasks in the `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` will be lost. I wonder if there is any good way to solve this problem. Can I persist this data and automatically read it when I restart?

I can use message queues, such as `rabbitmq`, to implement persistent data and restart the queue for automatic reading. However, I still want to know what methods can be used to implement persistent data with `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`.

I try to save the data in the database and synchronize the data with the database. My idea is to save these data in the database, and then delete the data of these tasks from the database after the task is completed. But when I use the `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`, I don't know whether these tasks have been completed. Therefore, I cannot read data from the database to determine whether the task is completed. The `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` has a method to judge whether the task is successfully executed. But what I want is that once the task is successfully executed, I will delete the task data in the database.

Maybe I can do another scheduled task to periodically query whether the task in `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` is executed successfully. But is there any better way to achieve my needs?

Comment: No worries, your English is very good! Have you considered using cron or systemd for scheduling these tasks?

Comment: @Thomas thank! But my requirement is that there are many different times to perform tasks, that is, the time for each task is different. My concern is that after these services are restarted, these tasks disappear and cannot be executed regularly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm worried about my stupidity. It's my stupidity. Obviously, I can judge whether to execute this task by synchronizing data in the database. I ignored it.